# R detect increasing/decreasing trend of time series

Tags: r, detection, trend

I have lots of time series, with period: day, week or month. With `stl()` function I can see how trend of particular `timeserie` looks like. I need to detect if trend of `timeserie` is increasing or decreasing. How can I manage that?

Or maybe someone could suggest another algorithm for trend detection?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? I am facing the same sort of problem.